# reate Dataframe from list of tuples with lists

Tags: pandas

I have some data like this

```py
data = [
    ('code', [kokyaku_kodo1,kokyaku_kodo2,kokyaku_kodo3,kokyaku_kodo4]),
    ('score', [hyoten1,hyoten2,hyoten3,hyoten4]),
    ...
]
```

And I would like to create a `Dataframe` like this

```
    code          score
0   some_code1    some_score1
1   some_code2    some_score2
```

I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

But this created a dataframe with shape

```
        0              1
0   some_code1    some_score1
1   some_code2    some_score2
```

Comment: what will be your expected output from given variable data?

Comment: some_code1, some_score1 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "columns" argument, like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,columns=['code', 'score'])
```

Other approach:

```
data=np.array([('code', [1,2]), ('score', [3,4])])
keys=data[:,0]
values=data[:,1]
d=dict(zip(keys, values))

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Output of `df`:

```
     code   score
0      1      3
1      2      4
```

Comment: getting ValueError: cannot use columns parameter with orient='columns'

Comment: @MarcelKopera, I added another approach to my answer